# How do we connect a .bna file with the peers nodes or channels created as per the byfn.sh script

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Using Hyperledger Composer we create a business network in which we are creating a .bna file consisting of model,script and permissions files.

How do we connect this .bna file with the peers nodes or channels created as per the byfn.sh script(provided in the build your own network tutorial) assuming that we have deployed the .bna file, started the network and generated REST-API's using composer commands in the command line interface.

Alternatively do we have to deploy the .bna file only using Playground and create nodes, peers and channels inside Playground? 
       Is this the way forward for production as well?

Answer (score 1):

Composer Playground is good for quick prototyping, collaborating with Business users and testing of networks early on in a project lifecycle. Composer Playground not intended to be used in Production.

The commands shown in [this tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) are suitable for Production, but bear in mind that the tutorial is a *single machine simulation* to show the process.

**UPDATED** - following comment:

In production, a developer is likely to use an editor such as VSCode or Atom (with Composer plugins) to write the code, and then use the `composer archive create` command to build the .BNA file itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link, which if followed one can create organizations peers etc but how to create the business network definition thereafter?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your query "how to create the business network definition thereafter". You can create a new bussiness network definition and then create archive file manually using commands and deploy the bna to the network that you have already created.

Commands--
 To create business network archive.

> composer archive create -t dir -n ../
>   (give appropriate paths to bna)

To install the bna on network.

> composer netowrk install -a --bnaFILEname -c --PeerAdminCard

Now Start the network.

> composer network start -c PeerAdminCard -n networkname -V version -A admin -S adminpw

If your peers are spread across multiple VM then also you can try the above steps I guess. Please keep posted.

Answer (score 0):

The .bna file deployed with the composer framework, which is an abstraction over hyperledger fabric. This .bna is translated as chaincode at fabric level. You can deploy either by playground or composer cli. But yes the example is just for demo purpose and single machine, whereas in production it should be in multiple machines and thus the ips should be changed. And should be deployed through kubernetes or docker swarm. FYI the composer implementation of fabric is not production ready yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.